# Creating slope map with different colors according to slope percentage or degrees

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, contour, slope

I have converted a dxf file with contour lines into a polyline shapefile, and I have used the Raster Analysis plugin to create a grayscale slope map from this shapefile. I would now like to have different colors for this shapefile according to different slope percentages (or/and degrees). I am an urban planner and this makes it easy to define places which are easier and safer to build. For instance:

> Green: 0-20%
>
> Yellow: 20-29%
>
> Red: 30-39%
>
> Purple: 40-100%

I have tried to change the colors in the slope tif layer properties but have been unable to understand how to do that. Is it possible?

I know that it is for relief maps and color according to elevation but haven't found similar information about slope.

Answer (score 3):

in the properties of your raster layer, select "style", then render type "single band pseudocolor". You can click on classify to specify your intervals, and you can select the color ramp that you find most appropriate.